# How does Vietnamese handle the equivalent of phrasal/separable verbs from English or Chinese?

Tags: vietnamese, analytic-languages, phrasal-verbs

I just learned [Vietnamese doesn't have phrasal verbs](https://yourvietnamese.com/learn-vietnamese/vietnamese-verbs/). Phrasal verbs are like "to beat up", "to wake up", "to shake hands", "to keep going", etc.. In addition to that, in English and Chinese, you have [separable verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb), where it's like "to **wake** your friend **up**", where there are words in between the verb words. To me it is so complicated how this works out, but that is beside the point.

So I have been looking for analytic/isolating languages (of which there seem to just be a handful), which also *don't have* phrasal/separable verbs. Vietnamese seems to fit the bill! So hoping to use that as inspiration in understanding how a language can work without phrasal/separable verbs.

How does Vietnamese handle the equivalent of these types of English phrasal/separable verbs? To me it seems they are useful constructs, but apparently Vietnamese can be by without them. How so? What would you translate these types of sentences in Vietnamese as (something with rich and complex phrasal and/or separable verbs)? Could you show a gloss (or a few) of Vietnamese sentences translated from English (or Chinese), and show how the gloss isn't a phrasal/separable form? I am trying to grasp how it is possible to *not* use these features in a language.

Comment: 1) ‘Shake hands’ isn’t a phrasal verb; it’s just a verb with an object. 2) (Mandarin) Chinese doesn’t really have separable or phrasal verbs either. It has various different types of verbal _complements_, which may in certain cases be separated from the verb by intervening words (though they normally aren’t), but you would never consider verb + complement a single verb form.

Comment: Why is there a [Chinese separable verb wiki page](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Separable_verb) then?

Comment: That’s just terminology. I’ve never heard those referred to as ‘separable verbs’ before, though I suppose it’s not a wholly misleading moniker. But their form and function is completely unlike separable verbs in Germanic languages. The Chinese ones are in my experience more often called _verbs with generic objects_, that is, verbs that avoid being intransitive by the addition of an object that adds little meaning (‘eat food’, ‘sleep sleep’ ‘walk road’, ‘run steps’). But they are still just verb + object constructions, and as such, the object can of course be separated from the verb.

Comment: Hm, looking more closely at Chinese separable verbs, it seems it refers not just to verbs with generic objects, but also to verbs with various complements. That’s kind of lumping apples and oranges together, but I suppose from a descriptive point of view there is _some_ sense in unifying them, since they do share _some_ characteristics. But mostly they are quite different and unrelated things, and none of them are in any way comparable to separable verbs in Germanic languages, Hungarian, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vietnamese **does** have verb compounds, and sometimes they can even be analysed as separable, in the same way as Mandarin Chinese. Ngyuen 1996 classifies these into several types:

A. Coordinate (V-V) Compounds:

> *nấu nướng* "to cook, to do the cooking", where *nấu* refers to boiling/steaming, e.g. of rice, and *nướng* refers to grilling.
>
> *Gạo đâu mà **nấu** với **nướng**!* How can I cook without the rice?

This use of *với* ("and") to emphasise each of the component verbs is a common rhetorical device.

B. Verb-Noun (V-N) compounds:

> *làm khách* "to be a guest"; compare Chinese 作客.

Some of these can have the noun separated from the verb ("free construction"), and others cannot ("solid"/"frozen"). Many, though by no means all, are loans from Chinese.

C. Verb-Complement (V-V', V-A) compounds:

> *đóng lại* "close + return/again"
>
> ***đóng** cửa **lại*** "to close the door"
>
> ***đóng** **lại** cửa* "to close the door again (as it wasn't done right the first time)"

There is also the category of subordinate compounds, with modifiers, like *quốc hữu hóa* "to nationalise".

But it is also true that the equivalent of phrasal verbs in English often use serial verb constructions with complements in Vietnamese:

> *[Tôi] **thức dậy** mỗi sáng vào lúc sáu giờ.* = I wake up every morning at 6.
>
> *[Tôi] **đánh thức** đứa trẻ **dậy** mỗi sáng vào lúc sáu giờ.* = I wake the child up every morning at 6.